# How to struct.pack() a variable length list in Python

Tags: python

For example when len(args) = 2:

```
args = []
args.append('arg1')
args.append('argument2')

bytes = struct.pack('B' * len(args), len(args[0]), len(args[1]))
```

However, I need to handle variable-length args, that is, len(args) = n, where n is any positive integer.

Comment: I think the module was designed for a C-like definition of `struct`, which never changes size.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
bytes = struct.pack('B' * len(args), *[len(x) for x in args])
```

To unpack this:

```
struct.unpack('B' * len(bytes), bytes)
```

Because `'B'` means *1-byte unsigned char*, `len(bytes)` can be length of it.

Comment: The problem is more about how to unpack this again.

Answer (score 0):

You probably should add a length field to your output, so you know how many things to read back in.  Or rather use a "number of strings" followed by "length of string1", "length of string2", ..., "length of stringn".